How to remove access when using Credential Manager?
I'm trying to migrate from OneTap to Credential Manager. Previously I was able to use GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess(). Now I cannot see any options. How to revoke the access when using CredentialManager?

Currently, you can continue to use the deprecated API that you had mentioned, namey the GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess(). We are planning to add an equivalent API either to CredentialManager or Google Identity Services that you can use.

Hey Ali. Thanks for answering my question. I will continue to use the deprecated API until you add the equivalent for revoking the access.

I'm trying to implement the same.
For me, GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess() fails with
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4
Did you run into this problem?

Ryan, 4 means user is not signed in. Are you sure your user is in fact signed in when you're calling that API?

I believe I am.
I'm signed in via Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context).authorize(authorizationRequest)
I can save data to Google Drive and I can see the connection in my Google Account's 3rd-party apps & services

I think I finally figured this out.  In addition to requesting Authorization for Google Drive with Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context).authorize(authorizationRequest) (which alone satisfies the use case to send data to Google Drive), I still need to explicitly sign in (authenticate) via Credential Manager -- in other words, no, I was not correctly signed in.  @AliNaddaf, thanks for the hint.

@AliNaddaf Hey Ali. Are there any updates related to an equivalent API either to CredentialManager or Google Identity Services? Thanks.

It will be coming, some other more urgent tasks have taken the priority.
